# javascript object property references

Tags: javascript, object, properties, reference

Can someone give the best explanation of what is going on here:

```
var o = {
    name: "jack"
};

var z = {
    name: o.name
};

o = {};
alert(z.name); // expected undefined, shows "jack" instead
```

Are object properties just references? Destroying the object o doesn't seem to destroy the referenced object (in this case the string "jack"). Or, is it the case that the "jack" referenced by o.name is actually destroyed but that z.name created a copy of o.name?

Best

```
// consider this too
var o = {
    foo: function () {
        return "hello";
    }
};

var z = {
    m: o.foo
};

o = {};
alert(z.m()); // hello is displayed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find this more interesting.

```
var o = {
    name: "Jack"
};

var z = {
    name: o 
};

//Above assignment of 'o' to z.name will create a new alias to object 'o'. 
//So both 'o' and 'z.name' point to same object.

//When you change value inside 'o' it will still reflect in 'z.name' 
//because both point to same object
o.name="Jill";
console.log(z.name.name); // Logs : Jill and not Jack.

// Now, here you are actually assigning a new object to 'o'.
// This means now 'o' refers to a new object. But this will no way affect 
// the 'z.name' reference, it still points to same object. 
o = { name : "Joe"};
console.log(z.name.name); // Logs : Jill again and not Joe
```

Comment: i think we can safely say that primitive types: numbers, strings, booleans, null, undefined have value semantics and all others (objects) have reference semantics. We can also say that the primitive types have reference semantics but that they are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are copied by value, not reference.

Even if that wasn't the cause, objects are only handled by reference so overwriting `o` with a reference to a new object wouldn't change any references to the old object.

Comment: Strings are generally copied by reference in a manner similar to objects. We just don't think about it so much because they're immutable. It's more of an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

> Are object properties just references?

Yes and No.

They are not references in the meaning of "live updating", when you change (or delete) `o.name` then `z.name` won't be altered.

They are references in the meaning of binding some arbitrary value (with a property name) to an object. These values will exist on their own, forgotten (deleted from memory) only when no one does have a handle on them any more.

You might be interested in the [overview of Objects](http://es5.github.io/#x4.2.1) in the EcmaScript specification.

> z.name created a copy of o.name?

Yes. JavaScript differentiates between objects (with changeable properties) and primitive values (which are immutable). All of these are copied by value - there is no call-by / assign-by reference in JS - and so strictly speaking both `z.name` and `o.name` reference two different values. However the object values are so-called *reference values* which reference the same property-value structures in memory whenever they are copied.